# Implement JavaScript's style of optional parameter in Python

Tags: python

### JavaScript style

Suppose I have a function takes two objects as optional parameters input, and some of the args in the objects has default value, in JavaScript, I may implement it like this:

```
function func(setting1, setting2){
    arga = setting1.a || 1;
    argb = setting2.b || 2;
    argc = setting2.c;
    ...
}
```

### Python implementation

There's some ideas comes to my mind, but i think none of them is actually "good".

---

Here's the first one:

```
params = {"arga":2, "argb":3}
def func(argc, arga=1, argb=2):
    ...
func(**params)
```

The question is, this type of implementation cannot support the semantic i want, that is, the setting1 and setting2 need two be separated since they serve for different sub-procedures. Also, It need to manually choose the default parameters's position carefully.

---

Here's the second one:

```
def func(setting1, setting2):
    try:
        arga = setting1.a
    except KeyError:
        arga = 1
    ...
```

I think it's quite ugly.

---

Maybe this is the best one:

```
def func(setting1, setting2):
    arga = setting1.get("a") or 1
    argb = setting1.get("b") or 2
    ...
```

---

Is there any good way to implement this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `settingN` is a `dict`, you can do this:

```
argZ = settingN.get('z', default_value)
```

So, if `settingN` doesn't have the key `'z'`, `default_value` will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by ugly, but this is closest to what you want I think:

```
def func(setting1 = None, setting2 = None):
    setting1 = "a" if setting1 is None else setting1 
    setting2 = "b" if setting2 is None else setting2
```

Note there is no real point to this in Python, since it supports default parameters and keyed calls, so

```
def func(setting1 = "A", setting2 = "B"):
```

called with

```
func(setting2="C")
```

will set only the second setting, and use default for the first. Of course, if the default involves a function call then you have to use your solution.

Comment: Since the parameters could be long

Comment: @user8510613 I did not understand the comment. In any case, the first solution is the most JS similar solution I know of, requiring no changes on the caller side (like requiring a dictionary).

Comment: You're right, i think i could use the ** operator to unpack the two parameter dict to different sub-procedure.